# Laravel Forge: Strange POST requests to server's IP address. Is this security issue?

Tags: php, laravel, security, forge

Over past many months I've been noticing these kind of post requests sent to server's IP address (and not the actual domain):

POST: https://10.10.10.10 (example ip address)

```
Array(
    [VV27nX0RBekcnH5Xxq3k6nAi7DDWtKcmijZlBTzxTzyG2t/8jB_uqDIYzNz4BO9jgEoIvz1h/rsM7jtQGPMILbaX45ms4QAkzZLYr/B_SSw3QecgyUNL4HrrTYHmFAhz1lKL_p8j7hWfbXreQmdOG5dJxeOHFE8_0FFJH0ghnbvKUNz_vubkpTPpLmSZDWHiwIvH_Zf0z_aS0PNv9x5dT_i05N3hDUVyCxf_w6kO3fbwTiO5mzUR8T9mxSpx4VsqtqyHFlzpaO0vAOrrrg6hNVng5bn/GtfT836gLNtTypRdaKPt_5ulXmtMW3LhumBEhZVOkRs8l4ut2ilojiWA4yr1_UQsyJ_KkT1bURpgukfOcJ2CpxY_qoufFev49CfRDf1Yo2/EGtFFLQMEC5KiyYk3jK1dhTxYnYc2UA] => =
)
```

and

```
Array(
    [CFmxzCAeUO9tiRHIZW7HYsp4vEA7kKafBZA/1vjhZps11d3KcekSYp3zzr6WiK1T4hSJq7Mt2FK4eEvf1BZcsUZkPoj9zVo3vf9ipiYSEJRhQCkn/eO8IOc9l4u8Oezov2L6CGxtIypb4emUv1zDr72yKcOr1JHp6BIMMBW_2_LMe95r71QfMnc56ahycnEkl82NPqfGN69XJAM16GlyipzML9p3/_99YKC0/9ch58EQmfQ6EOFpRlTmcQpee_FPAOA0lyAVVMGhh0k5SL_W4t61O1Jk8MvFWsRsClhycA/rLgO5KFKijq2A1bk6Xa8Y04aAL87RTd7sz2QMDr1B/mewWLNDAcMmecv2kixQzWNUf0/0GSuANEP5JmhUzLSPIlzIRuZFAJNMTrGjp6U] => 
)
```

And all these are made from IPs like these:

- IP: 83.35.164.71 (Andalusia, Albolote)
- 70.80.104.232 (Quebec, Montreal)
- 68.60.86.122 (Michigan, Battle Creek)

Generally these requests made at least a 100 times over an hour.

The server throws `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Should I be worried about these requests? Are they trying to exploit any security vulnerability?

Comment: Nothing to worry about. You're going to be tested from many angles over the course of your application, this is just one of those "pen tests" to see what you've got open.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

These requests are meant to verify backdoored systems and send/receive signals with them. As long as your application isn't returning any data, you're fine.